# PagerJs - page-href add undefined in href path

Tags: knockout.js, pagerjs

I'm using knockout in my asp .net mvc application and now i want to setup pagerjs. Following instructions, I have added this part of html for my navigation menu in main layout

```
<ul class="nav" data-bind="foreach: $__page__.children">
                    <li>
                        <a  data-bind="page-href: $data">
                    </li>              
 </ul>
```

and I have this in my partial view:

```
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'start', title: 'My Applications', alt:'My applications'>...</div>
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'statistics', title: 'My statistics', alt:'My statistics'>...</div>
```

However when it render html I got following results:

```
<a  data-bind="page-href: $data"  href="undefinedstart">
<a  data-bind="page-href: $data"  href="undefinedstatistics">
```

and my start div is not visible.

I cannot understand why this undefined is shown? Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to add

```
 <base href="absolute-URI-to-index.html/"/>
```

at the top of my DOM. I found it looking into the pagerjs code. However I switched to jquery.haschange to avoid adding base tag to my html.

BR,

Minja